# Combining Matern and Periodic kernels in coregionalized regression

Tags: gpflow

I am trying to build a multi dimensional GP regression, initially with two outputs f1(x), f2(x).
On one output is somewhat arbitrary, hence I would like to use a Matern kernel here: f1'(x)=K_Matern f1(x). The other output f2(x) shows seasonality where the amplitude is related to the value of f1(x): f2'(x)=K_season(x) f1(x). I have been trying to compose a suitable kernel by combining the two with a Coreg kernel:
K_Matern * Coreg * K_season. As this does not seem to work I was wondering where is the mistake in my thinking.

```
k1 = gpflow.kernels.Matern32(1, active_dims=[0], lengthscales = 1)
k2 = gpflow.kernels.Periodic(1, active_dims=[1], lengthscales = 1)
coreg = gpflow.kernels.Coregion(1, output_dim=2, rank=1, active_dims=[1])
kern = k1 * coreg * k2

lik = gpflow.likelihoods.SwitchedLikelihood([gpflow.likelihoods.StudentT(), gpflow.likelihoods.StudentT()])

X_augmented = np.vstack((np.hstack((X1, np.zeros_like(X1))), np.hstack((X2, np.ones_like(X2)))))
Y_augmented = np.vstack((np.hstack((Y1, np.zeros_like(X1))), np.hstack((Y2, np.ones_like(X2)))))

m = gpflow.models.VGP(X_augmented, Y_augmented, kern=kern, likelihood=lik, num_latent=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `k2` is operating on the same dimension of `X_augmented` as `coreg` (`active_dims=[1]`) - which is the column that's either 0 or 1 depending on which output it relates to, clearly not what you want! If you want to use different kernels on different outputs, you need to use the multi-output framework, there is a [multi-output notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/GPflow/GPflow/blob/develop/doc/source/notebooks/advanced/multioutput.ipynb#3.-Separate-Independent-Kernel-&-Separate-Independent-Features) in the GPflow documentation. Specifically, you probably want a `SeparateIndependentMok([Matern32(1), Periodic(1)])`. Note that in this framework you need to provide all outputs for each input, and instead of augmenting X with the index-into-output, Y has one column per output (so N x 2 in your example).